# Spring for Hadoop HBase

Tags: spring, spring-data, hbase, hadoop2, spring-data-hadoop

I have a question to Spring community.

As stated in the [article](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hadoop), Spring for Hadoop will no longer be supported on April, 2019.

Is (or will) there be any other Spring project for Hadoop, HBase (especially new versions 2.x.x)?